# How to query based on object value?

Tags: sql, database, crate

I have a crate db table with records like the one below:

```
  {
    "businessareaname": "test",
    "profile": {
      "phone": "",
      "fullname": "",
      "email": "abe-10@spatially.com"
    }
  }
```

I've tried querying with:

```
select * 
from myTable 
where profile['email'] = 'abe-10@spatially.com';
```

but nothing get's returned.  How can I pull records based on an email value that is in an object?

This isn't a flat table so this is my best attempt at showing the table structure.  The first row is the header and the next two rows are data.

```
    business name | profile:
                    - phone
                    - fullname
                    - email
    -------------------------------------
    "test"       | ""
                   ""
                   "abe-10@spatially.com"
   -------------------------------------
    "other one"  | "(415)884-9938"
                   "Abe Miessler"
                   "abe@test.com"
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure please?

Comment: @JorgeCampos - sure I gave it my best shot.  Kind of hard to do since it's not a flat table, so let me know if you're still confused at all.  The first row is the header.  The next two rows are data

Comment: Can you try `...where unnest( profile,['email']) = 'abe-10@spatially.com';`

Comment: Threw an error: `SQLActionException[UnsupportedFeatureException: unknown function: unnest(object, string_array)]`

Comment: There's nothing useful at the docs page best I could find was about object types in the JDBC section (https://crate.io/docs/clients/jdbc/en/latest/#types)  there the Crate Object maps to PostgreSql json type which means that `... where profile->>'email'='abe-10@spatially.com'` or something close to it should work. See it here in the postgresql doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: I just spoke with the CTO of crate and he told me i'm out of luck until their engineers can look into it.  Kind of disappointed in the product - this is really inconvenient :-(

Comment: Hoooly cr$%¨& .... for sure... to release a type without being able to use it in a query, what a mess... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you wrote should work and is correct.

Reasons it might not work is that the table schema is not correct, specifically:

- The email column was created with `INDEX OFF`
- The object column was created with column-type `IGNORED`
- There is a fulltext index / analyzer on the email column and so the email is tokenized.

Here a full working example:

```
create table t1 (profile object as (email string));

insert into t1 (profile) values ({email='abe-10@spatially.com'});

refresh table t1;

select * from t1 where profile['email'] = 'abe-10@spatially.com';
```

If piped into `crash` this would output:

```
CONNECT OK
CREATE OK, 1 row affected  (0.286 sec)
INSERT OK, 1 row affected  (0.082 sec)
REFRESH OK, 1 row affected  (0.065 sec)
+-----------------------------------+
| profile                           |
+-----------------------------------+
| {"email": "abe-10@spatially.com"} |
+-----------------------------------+
SELECT 1 row in set (0.087 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I looked at the table details and found that the email column was created with: `STRING INDEX USING FULLTEXT WITH (analyzer = 'standard' )` the object column was created as `OBJECT (DYNAMIC)` . With these settings the thee bullet points you mentioned should not be a factor - correct?

Comment: `STRING INDEX USING FULLTEXT WITH (analyzer = 'standard' )` is exactly what the 3rd bullet point is referring to.
Since the values are now tokenized you could query with `where profile['email'] = 'abe'` or with `where profile['email'] = 'spatially.com'`